# Excel - Auto-fill/number with custom pattern across columns and rows, while allowing duplication?

Tags: vba, excel

I have data similar to this, where my values in Columns B, D and F may repeat occasionally:

```
 Column A     Column B     Column C     Column D     Column E     Column F
 --------     --------     --------     --------     --------     --------
              Data1                     Data2                     Data3   
              Data4                     Data1                                         
              Data5                                               Data1
              Data3
```

What I need to do is auto-fill/number Columns A, C and E, first going horizontally on the sheet then vertically, using a custom pattern - essentially giving the data in Columns B, D and F an unique ID.

In doing so, I need to keep the following in mind:

1. A repeating value in Columns B, D and F does not get assigned a new ID, but receives the previously allocated ID.
2. Column B will always have data, thus I expect all rows of Column A to be filled.
3. Columns D and F may not always have data.

   - So, I only expect the rows in Column C to be filled if Column D contains data.
   - Similarly, I only expect the rows in Column E to be filled if Column F contains data.

What I expect to achieve as final result is:

```
 Column A     Column B     Column C     Column D     Column E     Column F
 --------     --------     --------     --------     --------     --------
 UR001        Data1        UR002        Data2        UR003        Data3   
 UR004        Data4        UR001        Data1                                         
 UR005        Data5                                  UR001        Data1
 UR003        Data3
```

Unfortunately my sheet is very long, spanning to nearly a thousand which is making it difficult to do the numbering manually. And if I need to introduce extra rows in the middle, I essentially end up breaking the sequence from that point and have to start numbering till the end, again and again.

I have tried searching for in-built formulas and vba code but I'm unable to find something suitable for my problem. Help, please!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because '*What I need to do is auto-fill/number Columns A, C and E...*' is **not** a specific programming problem and adding narrative debris like '*I have tried searching for in-built formulas and vba code but I'm unable to find something suitable for my problem. Help, please!*' does nothing to change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this out. It makes use of a Dictionary which stores previously identified Data Strings within columns B,D,F.

```
Sub BreadthSearchFirst()

Dim dict
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Set sht1 = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Dim ID, newID, key As String
Dim j, i, count As Integer

ID = "UR"
count = 1

'include the starting and last row number
startrow = 1
totalrow = 100

'loop over each row
For j = startrow To totalrow
    'loop over each column
    For i = 1 To 6
        'looks only in even columns
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
            'Checks if a Value is Present
            If sht1.Cells(j, i) <> "" Then
                'assigns the value as a key if the cell is not empty
                key = sht1.Cells(j, i)
                'checks if the key is present in the dictionary
                If dict.Exists(key) Then
                    'call the previously stored data if it exists
                    sht1.Cells(j, i - 1) = dict.Item(key)
                Else
                    'places the newID in the odd column
                    newID = ID & count
                    sht1.Cells(j, i - 1) = (ID & count)
                    'creates a new key within the dictionary
                    dict.Add key, newID
                    'increment the ID count
                    count = count + 1
                End If
            End If
       End If

    Next i
Next j

End Sub
```

A few things to note
you'll need to make changes if the columns are not the first 6 columns (i.e. A to F)
Modify the starting and end rows, there are methods available to locate the last row in a sheet and can be replaced with this accordingly. There shouldn't be any empty spaces in the even columns (B,D,F), if so it will recognise this as a data.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I was able to make this work for my case, with a few tweaks here and there!